# Is it possible to add Outlook Add-in for Mac

Tags: macos, outlook, ms-office, add-in, outlook-addin

I made a new Add-in using this tutorial:
https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted
I did manage to add it to Outlook Web App (OWA).
But while trying to add it to Outlook Mac, I noticed that there is no "Manage Add-ins" Or any add-in button inside the Outlook Mac app.
How can I then add my add-ins for MAC? is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently Mac Outlook 2016 does not support installing your own Addins. You can install Addin using OWA or Windows Outlook and access the same AddIn in Mac Outlook.Addins are associated with your email account and it will run on all Outlook clients.  However Windows Outlook supports more AddIn features than Mac Outlook 2016 as of now. Refer to compatibility sheet listed https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability . You can click on details to find the list of features supported.

Answer (score 4):

The marked accepted answer is now no longer correct.

Feature parity for Outlook o365 add-ins is now very good.  Add-ins can be directly loaded on a Mac using sideloading as explained at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing#sideload-an-add-in-in-outlook-on-the-desktop